# Communicating from html or javascript to python Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

I have read through all the postings and cannot find anything that will work for my program. I am using the mapbox js framework and want to send the users location 'position' to my python view code to store it in a database. When I do a console.log() in the js code it doesnt print anything. When I do a print in python it prints 'None'. I tried ajax like other posts had but nothing seems to work. Maybe I am going about passing data from templates to python code in the wrong way... Please help

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
</head>
</html>
```

home.html

```
{% extends "geotracker/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
 <body>
  <div id='map' width='100%' style='height:400px'></div>
  <form id="myform" name="myform">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" id="location" name="location"/>
 </form>
<script>

 mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mytoken';
 var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
  center: [-96, 37.8], // starting position
  zoom: 3 // starting zoom
 });

 // Add geolocate control to the map.
 var geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl();
 map.addControl(geolocate);

  geolocate.on('geolocate', function(e) {
  console.log('locating...');
  var lon = e.coords.longitude;
  var lat = e.coords.latitude
  var position = [lon, lat];
  var element = document.getElementById('location');
  element.innerHTML = position;

    $('#myform').submit(function (ev) {
    //ev.preventDefault();
    console.log('hello');
  });
  });
  </script>
 </body>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def home(request):

context = {
    "mclient": mclient
}
print("POST in view:\t%s" % request.POST.get('location'))

# get users location if authenticated
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    Fan.objects(user=str(request.user)).modify(set__currentPosition= 
 [0,0], image='http://localhost:8000/media/%s' % 
 request.user.profile.image, upsert=True)

return render(request, 'geotracker/home.html', context)
```

Comment: what have you `console.log()`? have you tried to see what's in `frm` and `frm.serilize()` also in python `print` just the `request.POST`? PS in your `ajax` I believe there should be a `url` field?

Comment: console.log is the same as a print in js. frm is the form. request.POST is an empty query dictionary. The problem is that the ajax and form submission never get fired because the console.log('submitting...') never executes.

Comment: alright, I didn't read it carefully.  as I know of `.submit` needs a `input` with type `submit` which means a button is needed else it'll just stay there trying to listen for a submit to happen.  As you are doing that inside the `geolocate.on` I would take out the `$('#myform').submit(fu` and run the `ajax` directly inside the `geolocate.on` compare these two, one is with a button and one not but open your browser inspect though. https://jsfiddle.net/mfv5eLow/ (with btn) https://jsfiddle.net/mfv5eLow/1/ (without btn) hopefully I am not getting the wrong idea

Comment: your edit left the `.submit` (from my example) inside of calling ajax directly. >.<" what I meant was, `.submit()` shouldn't be there, sryz for my poor english

Comment: I edited my code with the changes. Even when i comment out the preventDefault() it still will not print out 'hello'. However if I do the version with the button it will work but that may be because the input submit type is handling the event rather than the jquery. Is it possible I don't have jQuery correctly?

Comment: maybe I shouldn't use `.submit`.  What I meant by `.submit` before meaning the `$('#myform').submit(function (ev)` your ajax shouldn't be called inside this function.  The one with button works because if you write the code inside this function then it means it's waiting for a submit event to happen which only happens when you clicked a button.  But since you are doing this without a button in your html, move the ajax or at this moment as testing `console.log` out of the `$('#myform').submit(function (ev)`  this fiddle will not work but this is what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/49ykg3sn/

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out the ajax jquery statement but I figured out that I can just use plain AXAJ to send a Post request using XMLHttpRequest. Using this method I was able to submit a form with a post request without refreshing the page to get the users location from the Mapbox Api. I just have to send my auth token from Django's Admin panel which I can get from a python variable sent to my template.

```
geolocate.on('geolocate', function(e) {
  console.log('locating...');
  var lon = e.coords.longitude;
  var lat = e.coords.latitude
  var position = lon + " " + lat;
  var element = document.getElementById('location');
  element.value = position;
  var url = 'http://localhost:8000'
  var params = JSON.stringify({
      longitude: lon,
      latitude: lat
  });
// Create a new AJAX request object
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Open a connection to the server
request.open('POST', url, true);
// Actually send the request
var csrftoken = '{{ csrf_token }}'
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
request.send(params);
});
```